# executing query and then fetching results in pymysql python

Tags: python, pymysql

If I write,

```
cursor=db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute(query)
result=cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

this works and print results as a dictionary.

But if I write like this,

```
cursor=db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
result=cursor.execute(query).fetchall()
print(result)
```

it gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "senti4SDanalyze.py", line 22, in <module>
    constructMaleResults()
  File "senti4SDanalyze.py", line 12, in constructMaleResults
    result=cursor.execute(query).fetchall()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

why is that?

Comment: Because `cursor.execute(query)` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `result=cursor.fetchall()` the method `fetchall` is being called on the object `cursor`.

In `result=cursor.execute(query).fetchall()` the method `fetchall` is being called on the object (or native type) returned by the `execute` method.

To understand this better, explore with the built-ins `type` and `dir`:

```
type(cursor)
dir(cursor)
type(cursor.execute(query))
dir(cursor.execute(query))
```